# How to remove the white space at the bottom

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with this code I am working on. There's a white space at the bottom of the page at 1024px width and higher that I can't get rid of.

I've tried adding a padding-bottom, checking margins, checking heights, but nothing works. I'm still a beginner so I might've missed something. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2Yi1.png)
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGWpG.png)

I tried the height: calc(100vh-21px); and this happened
[Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVB8O.jpg)

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* STYLING */
body{
    background: hsl(0, 100%, 98%);
}

/* HEADER */
.logo{
    width: 28%;
    margin: 1.5em;
}
.hero-mobile{
    width: 100%;
}
.hero-desktop{
    display: none;
}
.logo-desktop{
    display: none;
}

/* MAIN SECTION */
.main{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    color: hsl(0, 36%, 70%);
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 2em;
}
h1{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    margin: 1em auto;
    letter-spacing: 12px;
}
.soon{
    font-weight: 600;
    color: black;
}
.main p{
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

/* EMAIL */
.email-form{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.email{
    border-radius: 40px;
    border: 1px solid;
    color: hsl(0, 36%, 70%);
    width: 70%;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0px 25px;
}
.email::placeholder{
    color: hsl(0, 36%, 70%);
}
.email:focus{
    outline: none;
}
.btn{
    width: 70px;
    height: 53px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    border-style: none;
    background:
        linear-gradient(135deg, hsl(0, 80%,86%), hsl(0, 74%, 74%));
    position: absolute;
    right: 10%;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 0 hsl(0, 36%, 70%);
}

footer{
    margin: 10% auto 1% auto;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px){
    .main{
        margin: 9% 15%;
    }
    .main h1{
        font-size: 4rem;
    }
    .email{
        width: 50%;
    }
    .btn{
        right: 25%;
    }
    .btn:hover{
        width: 90px;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 0 hsl(0, 36%, 70%);
        background:
            linear-gradient(135deg, hsl(0, 80%,86%), hsl(0, 74%, 86%));
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: width 0.5s;
    }
    .btn:active{
        outline: none;
    }
}

/* BIG SCREEN */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px){
    .logo{
        display: none;
    }
    .logo-desktop{
        display: block;
    }
    .hero-mobile{
        display: none;
    }
    .container{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
        height: 100vh;
        max-width: 1920px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

/* MAIN SECTION */
    .hero{
        /*    fixed resizing by putting image in css instead of html    */
        background: url(../images/hero-desktop.jpg) no-repeat center;
        background-size: cover;
        width: 40%;
    }
    .left{
        background: url(../images/bg-pattern-desktop.svg) no-repeat center ;
        background-size: cover;
        width: 60%;
        height: auto;
    }
    .text-area{
        position: relative;
        max-height: 1080px;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .logo-desktop{
        width: 20%;
        position: absolute;
        left: 20%;
        top: 5%;
    }
    .main{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: left;
        width: 50%;
        position: relative;
        left: 20%;
        top: 25%;
    }
    .main h1{
        margin: 5% auto;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 5em;
    }
    .main p{
        line-height: 1.5em;
        word-spacing: 3px;
    }
    .email-form{
        margin: 0;
        text-align: left;
        position: absolute;
        left: 19%;
        bottom: 10%;
        width: 60%;
        height: 60px;
    }
    .email{
        width: 70%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .btn{
        position: absolute;
        width: 110px;
        height: 100%;
    }

    footer{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <title>Frontend Mentor | Base Apparel coming soon page</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:300,400,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Feel free to remove these styles or customise in your own stylesheet  -->
        <style>
            .attribution { font-size: 11px; text-align: center; }
            .attribution a { color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%); }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <img class ="logo" src="images/logo.svg" alt="Base Apparel logo">
        </header>

        <div class="container">


            <div class="hero">
                <img class="hero-mobile" src="images/hero-mobile.jpg" alt="Base Apparel model">
            </div>

            <div class="left">
                <div class="text-area">

                    <img class ="logo-desktop" src="images/logo.svg" alt="Base Apparel logo">

                    <section class="main">
                        <h1> We're <br> <span class="soon">
                            coming <br>
                            soon </span> </h1>

                        <p>Hello fellow shoppers! We're currently building    our new fashion store. 
                           Add your email below to stay up-to-date with announcements and our launch deals.</p>
                    </section>

                    <form class="email-form">
                        <input class="email" id="email"type="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
                        <button class="btn" id="submit" type="submit">
                            <img src="images/icon-arrow.svg" alt="arrow icon">
                        </button>
                    </form>



                    <footer>
                    <p class="attribution">
                      Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>. 
                      Coded by <a href="#">Ken Yasuge</a>.
                    </p>
                    </footer>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried to run your code and I don't see any white space.

Comment: yes, no white spaces when tried your code, please share screen shot..

Comment: what browser are you using ken yasuge?

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies. I am using chrome. Here's a link to a github page: https://kenyasuge.github.io/base-apparel-coming-soon/

And here are some screenshots:
https://imgur.com/kiLzBbC
https://imgur.com/9naBG04

Comment: your screenshots don't show up for me, it says i have to sign up? anyhow it would be better if you would edit your question and add the images there. stackoverflow supports images in your questions.

Comment: @cloned yes I added the screenshots on the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use Chrome DevTools and inspect your text-area div, you will notice that the text area div is not starting at the top. And the problem is with a 5% top margin of your h1 inside the main class.

You can either

1. Use padding instead of margin: `.main h1 { margin: 0; padding: 5% 0 }`
2. Or set margin-top to 0 after the margin you're already using `.main h1 { margin-top: 0 }`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly put footer under container:

```
<div class="container">
...
</div>
<footer>
...
</footer>
```

Then add styles for body :

```
body {
    background: hsl(0, 100%, 98%);
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

and add style for footer :

```
footer {
    position: inherit;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS file you have written an media query for BIG SCREEN. In that media query search for text-area class. And change height 100% to this -

```
.text-area {
    position: relative;
    max-height: 1080px;
    height: calc(100vh - 21px);
}
```

Please try these. it will work

Comment: Although it fixed the white space at the bottom, it also messed up the position of the elements on the left side